# How to disable http alerts in Go

Tags: http, go

I have a problem with the following error when calling `http.ListenAndServe`:

```
http: Accept error: *ip* accept tcp too many open files; retrying in 10ms
```

How I can disable this? `ulimit -n` is 1024 and I can't change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot open anymore file descriptors and therefore you cannot accept more connections. If you can't change the fact you have three possible options to deal with this problem:

1. Leave it as it is: The standard library uses an [exponential backoff](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/net/http/server.go?name=go1.2#1624) to wait for a time when there are file descriptors again. This is generally a good practice and gives future clients a chance to get a slot. In fact, the `http` package does this for every *temporary* network error that occurs.
2. Close the connection when a temporary error like this occurs. This can be achieved by wrapping the `net.Listener` returned by `net.Listen` and modify it's `Accept()` method to drop the connection on temporary errors.
3. Ignore the message. If the message is the only thing that bothers you, you can simply set the `log.Output()` to `ioutil.Discard`. (While this is an option, I don't see the use of that. You will end up ignoring important error messages and wonder why your service does not work.)

I would prefer the first but there may be a case where you want the second, so here is an example of a connection dropping listener ([on play](http://play.golang.org/p/BurgcT59pu)):

```
type DroppingListener struct {
    net.Listener
}

func (d DroppingListener) Accept() (net.Conn, error) {
    for {
        conn, err := d.Listener.Accept()

        if err != nil {
            if ne, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && ne.Temporary() {
                log.Println("Dropping connection because:", ne)
                continue
            }
        }

        return conn, err
    }
}

func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler http.Handler) error {
    srv := &http.Server{Addr: addr, Handler: handler}

    l, e := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if e != nil {
        return e
    }

    l = &DroppingListener{l}

    return srv.Serve(l)
}
```

With this `DroppingListener`, the `Accept` method will return a connection as soon as there is
no more temporary error.

Comment: Ick. User will choose #3.  Will apply this change universally. Nothing will ever work and user will not know why.  This isn't your fault, of course.  Your answers are all correct, but I am afraid there's a problem with the thinking that lead to the question.

Comment: While I share you concerns, hiding the information is not going to help. I can't do more than warn not to do this. I edited answer #3 to be a more specific that this is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Have fewer than ~1,000 clients.

What are you hoping to happen here?  You don't seem to be able to meet your resource requirements.

Comment: Just how to disable allerts mess, Thk